# Why is my Contribution Detail Report (native CiviCRM Core report) not accurate?

Tags: civicontribute, financial-accounts

**Version:** CiviCRM 5.7.4/5 (patched for Contact images)

A Donor sent in a chq for $100 - Staff entered originally as a Donation. Then Edited the Contribution to make it a Memoriam Donation. CiviCRM generates the three entries - see below:

[image]

**Issue:** in Contribution Detail Report this Donor is listed as having donated: $300 - please see below. So somehow sums up the absolute value of the three amounts/financial account transactions that are linked to the single Contribution.

[image]

**Question:** why? Columns checked: Donor Name, Donor Email, Donor Phone, Financial Type, Payment Type, Check Number, Transaction ID, Date Received, Amount, Credit Card Type, Country

Update: there are no soft credits on this Contribution and the report is configured to pull Contributions only

Answer (score 4):

Ok figured it out: the report is fine if I remove the column ‘Credit Card Type’. Then I see $100 in the report!

So if you select column ‘Credit Card Type’ a non-credit card contribution like this chq are aggregated over the number of financial transactions associated with the contribution, b/c the field ‘Credit Card Type’ lives in the Financial Tables.

So this is definitively a different bug from the one referenced here as well; this bug is related to (unnecessary) financial transactions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/655) in the Contribution Detail report right now that will multiply gifts by the number of soft credits.

Comment: There are no soft credits on this contribution; I’ve updated the question.

Comment: The linked issue suggests it might not be limited to soft credits, i.e. `it's still a multiplication based on the number of "contributions" whether soft credit or not with the same ID`. Unless I'm misreading that.

Comment: Isn't a Memoriam Donation a soft credit?